# How does Keras determine the weights in the first layer of pre-trained models?

Tags: tensorflow, keras, conv-neural-network

Keras pre-trained models (VGG, ResNet, DenseNet, etc.) have weights established after training on ImageNet with input shape (224, 224, 3). However, Keras allows us to specify any other input shape (width and height should be no smaller than 32). How does Keras determine the initial weights of the first hidden layer when the input shape is other than (224, 224, 3)?

Answer (score 2):

It depends on parameter `include_top`.

Example:

```
import tensorflow as tf

model = tf.keras.applications.VGG16(include_top = True, input_shape=(299, 299, 3))
model.summary()
```

This will throw an error because when you pass `include_top = True` whole VGG16 architecture will be loaded including `Dense` layers.

As `Dense` layers care about the shape, it will throw an error. Because of the operation that `Dense` layers employ, shapes must be defined and matched with the input shape.

-- [Source Code](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/blob/3a33d53ea4aca312c5ad650b4883d9bac608a32e/keras/applications/vgg16.py#L182-L186) --

---

Second Example:

```
import tensorflow as tf

model = tf.keras.applications.VGG16(include_top = False, input_shape=(299, 299, 3))
model.summary()
```

This time, model only has convolutional layers because `include_top = False`. **Convolutional layers are just sliding filters on the image**. So input shape is not a problem for normal convolutions.

When you pass an `input_shape`, Keras creates an Input layer for that shape. Then creates the model, after that loads the weights.

-- [Source Code](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/blob/3a33d53ea4aca312c5ad650b4883d9bac608a32e/keras/applications/vgg16.py#L133-L134) --

The only constraint here is that, since these models are trained on RGB images, the new images should also have 3 channels.